# Find longest streak in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

please help me with getting streaks data. I have table of goal achievements

Table test

dt

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03. //3 days end of streak
2017-02-10 // 1 day
2017-02-15
2017-02-16
2017-02-17
2017-02-18 //4 days
```

I tried this in MySQL

```
Select dt, (select count(*) from test as t1 where t1.dt < t2.dt and datediff(t2.dt,t1.dt) =1) as str 
from test as t2
```

And got

```
Dt         str
2017-01-01  0
2017-01-02  1
2017-01-03  2
2017-02-10  0
2017-02-15  0
2017-02-16  1
2017-02-17  2
2017-02-18  3
```

Is it possible to get something like this

```
Dt.        Str 
2017-01-03  3
2017-02-10  1
2017-02-18  4
```

And get Max of it?

Comment: do you have a `dates` table in your database which holds all the calendar dates?

Comment: Vkp, no I don't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subtract row number (i.e the number of rows <= current row's date) from the current row's date to classify consecutive rows with one day difference into the same group. Then it is just a grouping operation to calculate the count.

```
select max(dt) as dt, count(*) as streak
from (select t1.dt
      ,date(t1.dt,-(select count(*) from t t2 where t2.dt<=t1.dt)||' day') as grp
      from t t1
     ) t
group by grp
```

Run the inner query to see how groups are assigned.

Comment: thank you vkp, you r genious!!!! It is exactly , 100 percent what I want! You saved me!

Comment: @RajeshPaul seriously?